# Azure triggered webjob aborted some times

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I had developed a time triggered Azure Web Job and published into Azure with Triggered type. Everything working fine but sometimes the web job goes into shutdown state without logging any exception information in web job dashboard logs and kudu logs.

Before posting question here, I read this [blog](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs) about Graceful Shutdown.

So, can anyone suggest me how to resolve the above issue.

Comment: Did you enable the `Always On` in the `Configuration` of your web app?

Comment: Yes @JoyWang, I am using premium app service plan.

Comment: Also, Added the idle time out parameter in the web app>application settings> for one hour by following this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596968/azure-webjob-timeout-configuration-settings

Comment: what is the frequency of web job set to run? (in minutes)?

Comment: Add an entry for WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT (not SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT). This is the time, in seconds, until Kudu will kill a WebJob that hasn't had any requests or output in the given time period. It only applies to triggered WebJobs.

Comment: Web Job runs on every one second. And I was already added WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For Continuous jobs, there is a default period of 5 seconds waiting for the job process to shutdown before getting killed.

For Triggered jobs, when a shutdown request is detected there is a 30 seconds default waiting period for the job process to stop.

You can change the grace period of a job by specifying it (in seconds) in the settings.job file where the name of the setting is `stopping_wait_time` like so:

```
{ "stopping_wait_time": 60 }
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19686) you could refer to.

Answer (score 0):

In our case triggered webjob has been aborted from time to time. It's occurred Azure aborts triggered webjobs just because it works too long. By default timeout is 2 hours. To increase the timeout in 2 times or what you need it's necessary to add in settings.job the following.

```
{
 "timeout": "04:00:00" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For our case, Besides set the website to always on, and also set WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT and SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT. It turns out we also need to deploy the website to the slot to make it work. We used to use a dedicated slot (without website deployed) to run the webjob and that doesn't work as expected, and webjob will become aborted after about 50 minutes without any error logs.

This may be very obvious so didn't see it mentioned in other places. Hope this can help people with similar situation.