# Getting Notification when triggered Azure web jobs Fails

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am new to Azure web jobs, I am creating a console application of .net framework for the webjob(**triggered**). I have noticed that the sometimes web job is failing because "SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT".
So Is there a way to get alert when these type of exceptions occurs, So I could go and restart the web job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please note that we can set `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` value in application settings. The detailed steps are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230266/10504999).

Also, you can use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) to catch the exception and get notification. You can enable it in your webapp.

[image]

reference:

[Set Alerts in Application Insights.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/alerts#how-to-set-an-exception-alert-using-custom-log-search)

**Update:**

I didn't have a webjob running, so I use `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` as a sample.

[image]

You can find all the logs here, you can test your query to filter the exception you want to trigger the alert.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Tony, Thanks for the Help. so by setting an alert in Application Insights, Can we get alert for web job failure for any reason it might be(not only for SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT)? Thanks.

Comment: @Chekrii Yes, you can custom the log search as a signal logic for triggering an alert.

Comment: @Chekrii There are also many general signals you can use directly, such as Failed requests.

Comment: OK @Tony, Thanks. right now I am looking at how to set an alert in Application insights for web jobs.

Comment: @Chekrii There is no specific document for seting alert for webjob, webjob is a feature under webapp. You need to custom the query to filter out the webjob exception. I will show you some screenshot in the answer.

Comment: ,Can you please provide an example for web job, that should be in the search query. I am unable to write a query that points to my web job.

Comment: @Chekrii You should post a new question, then your question will be visible to others.